# How do you clear changes in LinqToSql?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I have a combobox in my WPF app that is databound to my list of objects in my View Model.  When the user makes changes to the selected object and then selects another item before saving, I need to clear the changes made.

I thought I could use dataContext.GetChangeSet().Updates.Clear() but for some reason the collection is read-only.

I've also tried to use dataContext.Refresh but this doesn't work either as the object doesn't exist in the database, I created it manually from an SP.

Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to re-query into a separate data-context. You *can* negate an insert (from the change-set) by using `DeleteOnSubmit` (and the reverse), but I'd rather not, myself.

Comment: so are you saying to basically create a new datacontext and go get the data again?  If so then this is very slow as my collection has loads of items.  I was hoping there would be a copy of the object held somewhere so that any changes could be rolled back (like an undo feature).

Comment: There is an old version in the change tracker; but the idea of a data-context is for it to be a unit-of-work; not a database. IMO, it sounds like you're simply loading too much data into it to start with...

Comment: oh ok so there is an old version that i can use, where is it please?  I take your point about loading too much, but i can't see an alternative, thanks.

Comment: GetOriginalEntityState() on each table

Comment: In my opinion it would be a bad idea to re-query into a separate datacontext. If you don't refresh all tables there's a possibility of a "same key" error occurring. If you do refresh and you use immediate fetching, it could be an expensive operation. I would use HAdes's solution.

Answer (score 3):

As well as using Marc's approach using DeleteOnSubmit (or DeleteAllOnSubmit) to remove the inserts, the following will actually undo any updates aswell:

```
// clears any updates.  
ChangeSet changes = dataContext.GetChangeSet();
dataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, changes.Updates);
```

Comment: But I guess there is no need to clear the inserts since you can put the `InsertOnSubmit()` into an if-else block that depends on the dialog result.

Comment: Just to be clear, this doesn't remove inserts, and if you try it on `changes.Inserts`, it throws an exception because there are pending inserts, which just seems really weird to me.