# A Problem to Cancel linq2sql procedure

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

How can i cancel linq2sql procedure?
If it is not possible , has the EF ability to cancel sqlcommands?

> Command.Cancel()

Is there an equal command in ef or linq2sql for this ado.net ability?

**I want to cancel an stored procedure that execute a select query.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't call `SubmitChanges()`

Then, use a new `DataContext`.  Check this post [How do you clear changes in LinqToSql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158340/how-do-you-clear-changes-in-linqtosql)

Comment: Sorry bro,maybe my question wasn't clear.i want to cancel an stored procedure that execute a select query.

Comment: you mean you want to cancel *after** you've given the request?

Comment: @WishToBePro - once you've sent the query/scalar from your app to the database server you don't have control of it anymore.  This is universal, regardless of what ORM you use

Comment: I saw a solution that i must create a thread a execute my procedure in the thread and i must stop the thread.but what about the load on the dbms.if i stop thread the load will removed? The select is still running after stopping thread?

Comment: The IIS thread has nothing to do with what your db server is doing.