# Linq to SQL Clear Change after insert fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a simple form that pulls a list of Heat types from the database using Linq.  The from also has a text box where the user can enter a new Heat Type and a 'Insert New AC Type' button.  The code works fine except if they type in an existing Heat Type.  A message box comes up showing the error from SQL that duplicates are not allowed in the table.  After you close the box and correct the new ac type name and click the 'Insert New AC Type'. You still get the same SQL error duplicates are not allowed for the previous name.  It is like the first change is still waiting to be submitted.

```
    private void acNewTypeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ACType NewRecord = new ACType();
        NewRecord.ACType1 = acAddNewTextBox.Text.ToString();

        db.ACTypes.InsertOnSubmit(NewRecord);

        acAddNewTextBox.Text = "";
        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

        }

        loadDataGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158340/how-do-you-clear-changes-in-linqtosql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider checking if it exists first before adding it.

```
private void acNewTypeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var acType = db.ACTypes
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ACType1 == acAddNewTextBox.Text.ToString());
    // If it doesn't exist, add it.
    if (acType == null){
        acType = new ACType();
        acType.ACType1 = acType.Text.ToString();

        db.ACTypes.InsertOnSubmit(acType);

        db.SubmitChanges();

        acAddNewTextBox.Text = "";
    }
    // Already exists
    else{
        MessageBox.Show("AC Type already exists.");
    }

    loadDataGrid();
}
```